Copy-Pasting images in VS Code like in TeXstudo
I recently made the switch to VS Code with LaTeX Workshop from TeXstudio. So far I am liking it, but I miss one feature:
In TeXstudio I was able to copy an image, eg with the snipping tool, and paste it to TeXstudio, which automatically saved the picture in a folder of my choice and completed the \includegraphics command for me.
Is there a similar Thing in VS Code, or another fast way to inlcude pictures?
